# Error: negative length vectors are not allowed

Tags: r, dataframe, error-handling, pca

I have a relatively big dataframe in R called `df` which is about 2.9 gb in size, with dimensions
3701578 rows and 94 columns. I am trying to run the following command with the package `pls` to perform a principal component regression (pcr):

```
set.seed(1)
y_cols = tail(colnames(df),1) # select last column as dependent variable
x_cols = colnames(df)[-c(1, 2, 93, 94)] # PCA applied only to columns from 3 to 92, whose components become the regressors for pcr
formula = as.formula(        
  paste0("`",y_cols,"`", " ~ ", paste(paste0("`", x_cols, "`"), collapse = " + "))
) # to ease the writing down the formula
model <- pcr(formula=formula, data=df[df$date<19801231,], scale=FALSE, center=FALSE)
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in array(0, dim = c(npred, nresp, ncomp)): negative length vectors are not allowed
Traceback:

1. pcr(formula = formula, data = df[df$date < 19801231, ], scale = FALSE, 
 .     center = FALSE)
2. eval(cl, parent.frame())
3. eval(cl, parent.frame())
4. pls::mvr(formula = formula, data = df[df$date < 19801231, ], 
 .     scale = FALSE, center = FALSE, method = "svdpc")
5. fitFunc(X, Y, ncomp, Y.add = Y.add, center = center, ...)
6. array(0, dim = c(npred, nresp, ncomp))
```

Slicing the dataframe as in the formula gives a smaller dataframe of 751024 rows × 94 columns. At the beginning I thought (based on similar cases I found online) that this could be due to a memory limit, but actually I have around 1000 gb of RAM available so that is definitely not the case. Funny thing, I have no problem if I run the same command on the entire dataframe `df`. Creating a new object e.g. `new<- df[df$date < 19801231, ]` and then running the code does not help either. I managed to get it running if I set some missing data (relatively few) to zero in `new`. However, if I keep the missing data, the `pcr` command runs smoothly if I use the entire (bigger) `df`. Somebody has any idea about this behavior?

Comment: At least one of `npred`, `nresp`, and `ncomp` is negative or greater than `2^31-1` (integer overflow). That seems like a bug in `pls`, given that you, the user, haven't specified any of them directly.

Comment: So do you think that by specifying it this could solve the issue? Do you know how I could do this?

Comment: I took a look at the source code. `nobj` and `npred` are _definitely_ non-negative and less than `2^31`, but the default value of `ncomp` is `min(nobj - 1, npred)`, which would be -1 if `nobj` were 0. `nobj` is the number of rows of the model matrix constructed from `formula` and `data`. Can you paste the the output of `str(df[df$date < 19801231, ])`, or just `str(df$date < 19801231)`, into your question?

Comment: I would also recommend using `reformulate` to construct your formula, and checking that the formula is what you expect.

Comment: Thanks. I'm slightly puzzled, because you say that that replacing `NA` with 0 circumvents the error. But if you had any `NA`, then you should have seen an error from `na.fail` (called from `model.frame`) complaining about them, _not_ an error from `array` (called after `model.frame`). It would help if you found the _smallest_ subset of your data (fewest rows and columns) that reproduces the error, and pasted the complete output of `dput(<minimal data frame>)` into your question. Then we can investigate properly. You may need to reduce your formula accordingly.

Comment: In the mean time, I've rolled back your edit. I should have asked for `dput` output in the first place, not `str` output (though the `str` output _did_ confirm that your subset is nonempty, which was helpful).

Comment: I have problems using ```dput```. The minimal data frame reproducing the error is still around 30k rows by 10 columns, and I get an error about it: ```IOPub data rate exceeded. The Jupyter server will temporarily stop sending output
to the client in order to avoid crashing it.
To change this limit, set the config variable
`--ServerApp.iopub_data_rate_limit`.
Current values:
ServerApp.iopub_data_rate_limit=1000000.0 (bytes/sec)
ServerApp.rate_limit_window=3.0 (secs)```

Comment: I see - in that case, you may have to debug into `mvr` (called from `pcr`) yourself to determine what is going on. Do `debugonce(mvr)` before calling `pcr` to enter a debugger and execute the body of `mvr` line by line.

Comment: In the end I simply cleaned my dataframe such that it does not contain any missing (which anyway would not make a difference if ```na.action=na.omit``` as it should be) and it works smoothly now, no matter the dimension of the data.frame. Thanks for the help

Comment: OK - it might be worth reporting to the maintainer of `pls` that `mvr` does not generate a very useful error message when `nobj` is 0 and `ncomp` gets the value `nobj-1`.